# Firebase Data Not Saving to Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a problem attempting to add data to Firebase. Disregard the `vars` I don't use as I am trying different things and have commented out stuff I am not using at the moment.

But essentially, what I want to do is save this data to Firebase as follows:

1. A user enters his name and age in input boxes and then hits submit.
2. Once he/she hits submit, the function `addFB()` runs and ideally would create a child called `users`, and then under that, create a new child with the newly typed in `userName` (the User's name from the input box), and store his name and age in that child.

However, nothing is going to Firebase from this. Please help. Thanks in advance!

```html
<h2>Add</h2>
<input type=text" id="userName">
<input type="number" id="userAge">
<button id="btUpdateMessage" margin-bottom="20px" onclick="addFB()"> Update</button>
&nbsp;
<script>
```

```js
var lblCurrentMessage = document.getElementById('lblCurrentMessage'),
  userName = document.getElementById('userName'),
  btUpdateMessage = document.getElementById('btUpdateMessage'),
  userAge = document.getElementById('userAge'),
  rootRef = new Firebase('https://********.firebaseio.com');
var usersRef = rootRef.child('users');

function addFB() {
  usersRef.child(userName).set({
    Name: userName,
    Age: userAge
  });
  userName.value = '';
  userAge.value = '';
}
```

Comment: Use the latest version of 'firebase' library.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Comment: I have the reference to the Firebase SDK and everything is initialized there-- <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDSoVz0Ub43rygTCjgSxgkx5tGQRLTPUnE",
    authDomain: "addview-c21e6.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://addview-c21e6.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "605702281054"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

Comment: So that really doesn't help. Any other advice?

Comment: Please don't use the userName as the node key and also store it as a child value. It's best practice to save the user information in a node that has the userId as the key. The userId is guaranteed to be distinct and aligns with the userId that Firebase creates for that user.

Comment: @Jay You are correct

Answer (score 1):

*rootRef = new Firebase('https://********.firebaseio.com');*

The above code is not correct. This is the old method.

Just check the below code. This will help you.

```
function addFB() {
    var userName = document.getElementById('userName'),
        userAge = document.getElementById('userAge');

    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userName).set({
       Name: userName,
       Age: userAge
    });
}
```

Comment: @Taras is using the legacy firebase sdk and you are referring to firebase SDK 3.0 (new firebase).  Taras is confused.  He is following older tutorials.

Comment: This is the old method? I didn't realize i was following old tutorials...

Comment: Also, I just tried was you have, and it didn't work.

Comment: Don't you need th rootRef portion? Because when I try just doing firebase.database.ref, it doesn't know what that method is.

Comment: @devprashant Just check my first comment in the question section. I already mentioned to use the latest version firebase library.

Comment: @ti2005 yes i saw that, and upvoted your comment  yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```js
var rootRef = Firebase('https://********.firebaseio.com');
var contactsRef = rootRef .child('users');

function addFB() {
contactsRef.child(userName)
      .push({
          userName: document.getElementById('userName').value,
          userAge: document.getElementById('userAge').value
          });

  Name.value = '';
  Age.value = '';
}
```